# How to go back to a previous iteration in a function so that it re-executes

Tags: java, function, recursion

I have a recursive function to display a tree(I am not allowed to share the code but i really need help figuring this out)
   void display(node root)

```
    1.displays element held by root  
    2.ask for a key k  
    3.looks for child of root (calling it CHILD)that contains key k   
    4.If key k is 'Z' then return 
    5.else calls display(CHILD)  


                     A
                  /  |    \
                B    C     D
              / \        /  \
             E   F      G    H
```

This function has to achieve the following,
As you see in the picture

Output
A
Choose a node to view:A
B C D
Choose a node to view:B
E F

This, I am able to achieve but how would I go back to the iteration that displays B C D in order to give D as the next node to view and get G H as the display?
i.e.
Output
A
Choose a node to view:A
B C D
Choose a node to view or enter Z to go back to previous level:B
E F
Choose a node to view or enter Z to go back to previous level:Z
B C D
Choose a node to view:D
G H
Choose a node to view or enter Z to go back to previous level:

Comment: Guys, mention the reason of down-vote, he is a newcomer, Won't even know what he did wrong. So mere down-voting would not work.

Comment: Yes, please be kind enough to let me know why you are down-voting.I'll edit my question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I really don't see the problem. Note that even if you're not able to show the actual code you should be able to produce code that could work as a placeholder for this question. Without code this question is not about java anyway.

Comment: You mentioned that you have a recursive function. Consider looking into the basics of recursion: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/

Comment: I've edited my question to show what I've done. The program terminates  but doesn't go to the previous iterations.

Comment: I need the previous iteration to re-execute not just return control to line after the function call

Comment: any code for this??

Comment: The close votes are (at the moment) because *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]* (3 votes)

Comment: My question isn't about debugging. Rather it is about how I can get a previous iteration to re-execute.

Comment: I didn't vote to close this question, but this is the way it works, people vote even if you disagree or argue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As if I understand your question you have a interactive system where the user controls the traversal. For your problem you shouldn't use a recursive function. You should better use a stack where

1. You push the selected node, when the user chooses a node from the presented list of nodes.
2. You pop the the top node from the stack, when the user chooses the option Z.

**Edit**: In a simple system you may use a recursive function, too. In case 1 above you call the function with the selected node, and in case 2, you return from the function. But this should only work if you can handle the user input in the function (e.g. text UI).

Comment: I understood what you are suggesting.As you said I may not need a recursive function at all. I will try a stack implementation. As of now, I am taking user input as text. Eventually I will develop a UI that requires the user to click on the node they'd like to view.

Answer (score 0):

If your nodes are objects and they aware of their children and parents, you can try something like this (pseudo-code):

```
void myMethod( Node)
{
    show all children of Node;
    take input from user;
    if(node choosen)
        myMethod( node);
    if( got Z in input)
        myMethod( Node.parent);
}
```

You just need a starting method for first call and something to break this infinite loop.

**UPDATE:** this is update that takes in consideration what @macmoonshine said. In this case nodes don't need to know who is their parent. There's still need for starting method and break.

```
void myMethod( Node)
{
    while (true)
    {
    show all children of Node;
    take input from user;
    if(node choosen)
        myMethod( node);
    if( got Z in input)
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should return when selecting option Z, and not make recursive call. Furthermore, the node in many tree implementations have no access to their parent element.

Comment: @macmoonshine If I return, I'm done. It will go back to previous method, but it will just end. You can't do that.

Comment: No, you will go one level higher. You should also include a loop for that case in your code which will present the selection dialog again.

Comment: @macmoonshine I updated my answer to include what you said. Added a loop and there's no need for knowing parents.

Comment: This terminates the execution. I needed re-execution of the previous iteration. I tried using stack and it works.